# How to inject a JS object which can be called as a constructor in Android?

Tags: javascript, android-webview, qtwebkit

I need to implement a JS object and use it like this (JavaScript code):

```
var mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

It was fine in QtWebkit and this is how I inject this JS object (C++ code):

```
static JSClassDefinition SomeClassDefinition = {
    .....
    callAsConstructor: SomeClassCallAsConstructor,
    .....
}

webview->addToJavaScriptWindowObject( context, "SomeObject", & SomeClassDefinition );
```

I'd like to port this module to Android and I try to use WebView:addJavascriptInterface() to inject this this into WebView in Android. Somehow it can't be used as a constructor like this:

```
var mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

The result is always undefined.

How can I make this work in Android just like in QtWebKit?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works on Android.

When you inject a JavaScript object into Android's webview, an instance of the Java object is bound to the javaScript `window` object.

For example:

```
WebView.addJavaScriptInterface(new Object() { ... }, "mediaPlayer");
```

Will allow you to call Java methods on the Java object via `window.mediaPlayer` in JavaScript.

[Android API Reference: WebView::addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I use this WebView.addJavaScriptInterface() to inject a JS object into Android's WebView. The problem is that the injected object can't be used as a constructor like:
    var mp = new MediaPlayer();

Comment: As I said, I'm afraid that's working as intended. It just doesn't work like that.